# Fusion 12.1 on Big Sur 11.2.3 Cant resolve: Could not connect 'Ethernet0' to virtual network

Tags: network, wifi, virtualization, ethernet, vmware

I am new to this page but excited to hear some answers from experts.

I am new to the VMware Fusion 12.1 Pro and I installed the latest build of Windows 10.
Every time I run the emulator, I generate the error:
Cant resolve: Could not connect 'Ethernet0' to virtual network.

So, after googling and hearing from other people that had the same issue, the resolution is to build a new NAT configuration or use Bridged on Autodetect. For the heck of it, I tried all of the other configurations but the results were the same.

Some suggested reboot, I did both the VM and the machine. It is a 2018 Macbook Pro 15 with 2.6ghz i7.

I tried to follow the steps here:
https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Fusion/12/com.vmware.fusion.using.doc/GUID-7D8E5A7D-FF0C-4975-A794-FF5A9AE83234.html

However, as soon as I get to the network preferences, all of the options are not clickable, it is in a sense "greyed out"

This is my work computer but I believe I am an admin, could the company have a security setting blocking? They gave me the license for VMFusion?

[image: pic1]
[image: pic2]
[image: pic3]

Comment: You should explore the VMware community https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Fusion/ct-p/3005-home. You will find that others have had trouble with NAT and BS.  Myself, I always use Bridged Networking which works without any trouble - so I don't have an answer for you!

Comment: To nitpick: VMware is not an "emulator", it is a "hypervisor" which runs "virtual machines".  But that is irrelevant for your problem as I am sure we all know what you mean!

Comment: I have the same configuration (Fusion Pro 12.1+Big Sur 11.2.3) and I'm surprised Bridged Networking doesn't work for you, I've seen the dreaded "Could not connect 'Ethernet0'" error quite a few times when using NAT, and switching to Bridged Networking has worked nicely so far. As for the greyed out options in the Network pane, in my installation there is no "MTU" option, and I have a lock that I have to click to make changes (I'm not an admin). You may want to create a standard user on your Mac, log in with that user and check if the Network pane is still greyed out after clicking the lock.